# Apart from mayor, what other political positions have a maximum age in The Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands

The mayor of The Hague (*Den Haag*) in The Netherlands, Jozias van Aartsen, is stepping down.  He has reached the age of 69 years, and in The Netherlands, this is the maximum age for a mayor, at which they are forced to retire. (Source: Kim van Keken, *‘Ik heb grote bewondering voor Angela Merkel’*, in *[De Groene Amsterdammer](https://www.groene.nl/artikel/ik-heb-grote-bewondering-voor-angela-merkel)*, 23 February 2017).

Until now, I did not know there was such a forced retirement.  Are there any other political positions in The Netherlands that have an absolute age limit, beyond which politicians are forced to retire?  At least for the lower house (*Tweede Kamer*) there is [no age limit](https://www.parlement.com/id/vh8lnhrre0zu/oudste_tweede_kamerleden).

*(NB: the position of mayor in The Netherlands is not a powerful one.  Mayors are not elected but appointed by the Crown.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of [*dijkgraaf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkgraaf_(official)) seems to have the same age-restriction as mayors do. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkgraaf_(official)), the dijkgraaf chairs *"both the legislative and executive council, while having both ceremonial and representational roles as well as his own portfolios."* Historically, this position seems to have been more political, from the same Wikipedia link:

> In medieval times and earlier however, the water boards were the same as municipal, and since it was a country of duchies, the Water board (Waterschap) was in governmental terms the equivalent of a city (Stad), and thus also the highest form of government.

From the [procedure on appointing chairs of the water board (in Dutch, PDF)](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/binaries/rijksoverheid/documenten/circulaires/2018/02/23/procedure-benoeming-voorzitters-van-waterschappen/Circulaire+procedure+benoeming+voorzitters+van+waterschappen.pdf):

> Als de voorzitter van een waterschap de leeftijd van 70 jaar
> bereikt, wordt hem of haar met ingang van de eerste dag van de volgende maand
> bij koninklijk besluit eervol ontslag verleend.

Translated by me:

> When the chair of a water board reaches the age of 70, they will be honourably discharged by Royal Decree in the following month.

Unfortunately, I don't know what specific law it is that stipulates this, but I imagine it is the same law that applies to mayors. I did search the ['*Waterschapsbesluit*'](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0023025/2019-02-15) ('law on the water boards') but could not find the relevant passage.

#### Example

According to this [document by the Hunze en Aa's Waterschap](https://www.hunzeenaas.nl/about/bestuur/vergaderingen/VVS/Documents/2016-09-21/07.0%20Procedure%20benoeming%20dijkgraaf.pdf), on the first of August 2017 their dijkgraaf's appointment had to be ended because he turned 70 in the previous month. The word *'rechtswege'* translates as *'legally'* meaning the ending of the appointment was because of some law.

The relevant passage from the aforementioned document (in Dutch):

> Omdat de dijkgraaf op 8 juli 2017 de leeftijd van zeventig jaar bereikt eindigt zijn benoeming van
> rechtswege op 1 augustus 2017. Dit ontslag wordt bij Koninklijk Besluit verleend.

Roughly translated by me:

> Since the dijkgraaf turns 70 on July 8, 2017, by law, his appointment ends on August 1, 2017. This termination is granted by Royal Decree.